# Where to start with extracting and listing data from Foursquare

Tags: jquery, json, html, foursquare

Foursquare has a few examples of how to use their API, one main one of which I had trouble getting it to work. But my main question is how can I extract and display a list rather than points on a map of nearby popular places?

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/tutorial

I'm very new at this and don't know what methods or languages to use (json, jquery, etc.).

Anyone have any direction or help getting me started with how to pull and list data from the URL I can create through Foursquare, https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/trending?

Here's the code they use to call and mark on a map, but I'd prefer a list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>foursquare :: Explore Sample</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" id="jquery"></script>


  <link href="/styles/leaflet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/styles/apisamples.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="/scripts/apisamples.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/jquery.ba-bbq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/third_party/wax.leaf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100%; }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    /* Give our markers a background image */
    .leaflet-marker-icon {
      background: url(https://foursquare.com/img/pin-blue-transparent.png);
      padding: 6px;
      padding-bottom: 17px;
      top: -6px;
      left: -6px;
      }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var config = {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    authUrl: 'https://foursquare.com/',
    apiUrl: 'https://api.foursquare.com/'
  };


  //<![CDATA[

  /* Attempt to retrieve access token from URL. */
  function doAuthRedirect() {
    var redirect = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
    var url = config.authUrl + 'oauth2/authenticate?response_type=token&client_id=' + config.apiKey +
        '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect) +
        '&state=' + encodeURIComponent($.bbq.getState('req') || 'users/self');
    window.location.href = url;
  };

  if ($.bbq.getState('access_token')) {
    // If there is a token in the state, consume it
    var token = $.bbq.getState('access_token');
    $.bbq.pushState({}, 2)
  } else if ($.bbq.getState('error')) {
  } else {
    doAuthRedirect();
  }

  /* HTML 5 geolocation. */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
    var lat = data['coords']['latitude'];
    var lng = data['coords']['longitude'];
    /* Create map. */
    var map = new L.Map('map_canvas')
      .setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 15);
    /**
     * This is a sample map url that you need to change.
     * Sign up at http://mapbox.com/foursquare for a custom map url.
     */
    var mapboxUrl = 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/foursquare.map-b7qq4a62.jsonp';
    wax.tilejson(mapboxUrl, function(tilejson) {
      map.addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson));
    });

    /* Query foursquare API for venue recommendations near the current location. */
    $.getJSON(config.apiUrl + 'v2/venues/explore?ll=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&oauth_token=' + window.token, {}, function(data) {
      venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
      /* Place marker for each venue. */
      for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
        /* Get marker's location */
        var latLng = new L.LatLng(
          venues[i]['venue']['location']['lat'],
          venues[i]['venue']['location']['lng']
        );
        /* Build icon for each icon */
        var leafletIcon = L.Icon.extend({
          iconUrl: venues[i]['venue']['categories'][0]['icon'],
          shadowUrl: null,
          iconSize: new L.Point(32,32),
          iconAnchor: new L.Point(16, 41),
          popupAnchor: new L.Point(0, -51)
        });
        var icon = new leafletIcon();
        var marker = new L.Marker(latLng, {icon: icon})
          .bindPopup(venues[i]['venue']['name'], { closeButton: false })
          .on('mouseover', function(e) { this.openPopup(); })
          .on('mouseout', function(e) { this.closePopup(); });
        map.addLayer(marker);
      }
    })
  })
  //]]>
  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The venues/trending API call returns trending venue data formatted in JSON. You can visit https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/trending%3Fll%3D40.7,-74 to inspect the data returned from the API. You can use Javascript (or other languages) to manipulate the JSON to get a list of trending venues.